# Glob importing in react native

Tags: react-native, glob

I can do this in webpack with https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob

```
import * as foo from '../foo/*';
```

with a glob import extension. Is this possible in React Native?

Comment: What kinds of extensions would you like to support? The react native packager let's you omit `.js` extensions by default.

Comment: @ArneHugo should work like https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob